# Remove null byte every X byte c++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, arrays

I have a buffer type like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = {
   0xB8, 0xB8, 0x00, 0xB8, 0xB8, 0x00, 0xB8, 0xB8, 0x00, 0xB8, 0xB8, 0x00,..
};
```

So I need to remove the null byte every **X** (every 2 bytes in this example). I **don't want to remove all null byte** because in my buffer I have melt bytes.
So just need to remove a range and in WinAPI. How can I do that?

I'm still not very comfortable with C++, also the **buffer can be big**.
I think the right way is by copy the buffer by `memcpy` in a loop but I can't find the syntax.

Comment: What type do you want the output to be placed into? Are you using the standard containers? Like std::vector?

Comment: i don't want to use Standar Library just WINAPI

Comment: Kind of weird not to use standard library. Anyway, what data type do you want the output to go into? And is this really C++, or is it really just C put through a C++ compiler?

Comment: "Unsigned char" is not in the WINAPI, you are already violating your requirements.  Might as well give in and use the standard library.  It's okay, it is standard.

Comment: in output i need same format in a unsigned char*, and yes is more like c compiled in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't want to use any of the more powerful features of C++ so I suspect that you are really looking for a C style routine. That would look like this:

```
void copyskip(void *dest, const void *src, size_t srclen, size_t skip)
{
    size_t destidx = 0;
    for (size_t srcidx=0; srcidx<srclen; )
    {
        if ((srcidx+1) % skip != 0)
        {
            ((char*)dest)[destidx] = ((char*)src)[srcidx];
            destidx++;
        }
        srcidx++;
    }
}
```

You'd need to allocate the destination buffer before calling. And for your example you would pass 3 for the skip parameter.

Personally I'd much rather do it using C++ standard containers, but this is what I think you asked for.

Comment: This has seemed to work as i wanted, but how i can get the output size ?

Comment: that is given by `srclen - srclen/skip`